# Pandas transform date string from format mm/d/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy to dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: regex, pandas, date

I have a Pandas data frame which contains a column with dates. The dates are represented in by a string in the format mm/dd/yyyy.

But I have a **problem** with the **format of the day**: Dates until the 9th day of a month are in the format **mm/d/yyyy**. For example the first december 2008 is displayed as 12/1/2008. The 10th day until the end of a month are displayed as **mm/dd/yyyy**. For example the 17th december 2008 is represented by 12/17/2008.

My **target** is to transform the all dates into the form **mm.dd.yyyy**. The could would represent the above expamles as: 12.01.2008 and 12.17.2008

My idea is to just write the day, month and year into seperate columns and then connect the strings in the format mm.dd.yyyy

So far I have tried to withdraw the year and the month just by their position in the string *(see code and example below)*. But this does not work with the days as there are two cases: the day has either one or two digits.

My idea is to just use a regular expression It is basically the case *backslash one or two digits and a backslash*. But I do not know how I can express this as a regular expression.

Or is there totally different approach which is much simpler?

Thank you for the help in advance! I am sure that there is a way to do that with regular expressions. But I am also grateful for totally different approaches.

```
import pandas as pd

# example data frame with dates in the format mm/d/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['12/1/2008','12/5/2008','12/10/2008','12/17/2008']})

# withdraw month
df['month'] = df['date'].str[:2]
# withdraw year
df['year'] = df['date'].str[-4:]
# withdraw day - this is my problem
df[day] = df['day'] = df['date'].str.extract(r'[\]\d*')

# generate string with dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy
df['date_new'] = df['month'] + '.' df['day'] + '.' + df['year']
```

From the code of **df['day']** I get the following error: **error: unterminated character set at position 0**

Comment: I think the simplest solution is `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`. It parses that format properly and with the `datetime` dtype your life probably gets a lot easier.

Comment: That was the answer to the problem (see accepted answer)! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m.%d.%Y')
```

Output:

```
         date
0  12.01.2008
1  12.05.2008
2  12.10.2008
3  12.17.2008
```

---

Another thing to bring to your attention if you want to extract days, months, years or so, pandas has a special `dt` functionality for datetime types, hence, you need to convert your column first into that type.

You can access days and months like this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
```

You will get something like:

```
        date  month  day  year
0 2008-12-01     12    1  2008
1 2008-12-05     12    5  2008
2 2008-12-10     12   10  2008
3 2008-12-17     12   17  2008
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!
I used to_datetime and strftime at other cases but did not think that this is possible in this case.

Thaks a lot!

Comment: Done! Accepted it.